# When setting a new region, iOS simulator automatically shows a notification

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, mapkit

I've created a new project in Xcode to test some stuff of MapKit and I noticed that when I simulate a new location, the simulator shows a notification with some text (and sound). Here's how it looks:

[image]

I haven't implemented anything for it. I've just implemented a single method of `MKMapViewDelegate` for showing user's current location. Here is the code for that:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

I'm curious whether it is a default setting of a simulator, and if not, where the code for that kind of behaviour is implemented. If you know the answer, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: It appears that you have another app installed on your simulator called "geofencing region" that is monitoring for a region and displaying a local notification when you leave the region.

Comment: @Paulw11, oh yes. I've just seen that the notification was called from another app, because it always checks user's location, not only when it's used. I've completely forgotten about that app. Thanks for mentioning that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UNLocationNotificationTrigger` object causes the delivery of a notification when the device enters or leaves a specified geographic region.

As by selecting different region, you are leaving existing region - it sends out a local notification by using region change trigger.

Check out more details at following apple documentations -

- [Region Notification trigger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unlocationnotificationtrigger)
- [Region Monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html)